# Reporting zero inflated negative binomial regression in APA style

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I have results to a Zero-inflated negative binomial regression. What is the general "formula" to reporting the significance of a coefficient in the APA style. Is it similar to the "formula" for reporting the results of a multi-variate linear regression model? Which I believe is:

(F(a, b) = c, p < d)

where a is the regression df, b is the residual df, c is the test statistic, and d is the p-value. Or is it completely different?

Comment: If you have lots of them, you are probably better off placing them in a table along with p-values.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the [*APA Publication Manual*](https://www.apastyle.org/manual/) at hand, but I don't think there is anything specific for a negbin regression in there. I would report it in a similar way to a correlation coefficient. For instance, report your estimated parameter, the value of whatever statistic you are calculating (e.g., $t$ or $z$), the degrees of freedom and the $p$ value.